# Min date flag in select

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with records for sales of products.
For the purpose of sales count a product should only be counted one time. 
In this scenario a product is sold and reversed several times and we should only consider it in the month with minimum date and rest all the dates should be marked no.

Eample:

```
Product Month   Sales flag
A       Jan-01  Y
B       Jan-01  Y
A       Feb-01  N
C       Feb-01  Y
```

How can I write a select from the table indicating as above. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried and failed.

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: Hint: Use `row_number` with `partition by`.

Comment: select InternalVehicleNumber, ZZFCAI_TYPE,ACTIONDATE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY actiondate ORDER BY actiondate) row_num from   [dbo].[RetailFactTest] rt
 where  InternalVehicleNumber='0000899765'    The result is InternalVehicleNumber ZZFCAI_TYPE ACTIONDATE row_num
0000899765 21 2019-04-09 1
0000899765 59 2019-04-09 2
0000899765 99 2019-05-02 1 How do I create a flag on this now. Like here 2 shold be a flag saying do not count.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add code. Code in comments isn't readable.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that ordering by "Jan-01", "Feb-01", etc... is tricky because you need to sort numeric values stored as text. This is one of the uses of a calendar table or data dimension. In my solution below I'm creating an on-the-fly date dimension table with "Month-number" you can sort by...

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
  Product   CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  Mo        CHAR(6) NOT NULL
)
INSERT @table VALUES
('A', 'Jan-01'),
('B', 'Jan-01'),
('A', 'Feb-01'),
('C', 'Feb-01');

-- Solution
SELECT f.Product, f.Mo, [Sales Flag] = CASE f.rnk WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM
(
  SELECT t.Product, i.Mo, rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Product ORDER BY i.RN)
  FROM   @table AS t
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT i.RN, Mo = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, i.RN-1, '20010101')),3)+'-01'
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
      FROM   (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)
    ) AS i
  ) AS i ON t.Mo = i.Mo
) AS f;
```

**Returns:**

```
Product Mo     Sales Flag
------- ------ ----------
A       Jan-01 Y
A       Feb-01 N
B       Jan-01 Y
C       Feb-01 Y
```

Comment: This is what I wants to acheive with data in one table. I have got two scnarios. I did a partition by but the two different scenarios is causing the problem.

select InternalNumber, AI_TYPE,DATE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AI_TYPE ORDER BY actiondate) row_num from   
[dbo].[XFact] where InternalNumber='0XX'

Comment: InternalNumber AI_TYPE DATE row_num
0XX59 2019-01-11 1
0XX59 2019-03-27 2
0XX99 2019-03-27 1
0XX99 2019-07-26 2

select InternalVehicleNumber, AI_TYPE,ACTIONDATE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY actiondate ORDER BY actiondate) row_num from   
[dbo].[XFact] where InternalVehicleNumber='0YY'

InternalNumber AI_TYPE  DATE row_num
0YY 21 2019-07-31 1
0YY 59 2019-07-31 2

Comment: Need it very urgently now and I have spend quite some time to figure it out.